# Errores de lectura con clases serializables y getExternalFilesDir()

Tags: android-studio, arraylist, guardar

Tengo un programa que guarda un registro de llamadas en dos archivos, uno ordenado y otro desordenado. Los dos archivos están guardando correctamente, el problema viene en la lectura.

```
    //Historial.csv SE GUARDA DESORDENADO
    public boolean guardaLlamadasDesordenado(Llamada llamada, Context cont) {
        boolean result = true;
        File f = new File(cont.getFilesDir(), "Historial.csv");
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
            fw.write(llamada.toString() + "\n");
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    //Llamadas.csv SE GUARDA ORDENADO
    public boolean guardaLlamadasOrdenado(Llamada llamada, Context cont) {
        boolean result = true;

        ArrayList<Llamada> listaLlamadas = leeSerializable(cont);
        listaLlamadas.add(llamada);
        Collections.sort(listaLlamadas);

        File f = new File(cont.getExternalFilesDir(null), "Llamadas.csv");
        FileWriter fw = null;

        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(f, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < listaLlamadas.size(); i++) {
                fw.write(listaLlamadas.get(i).toString() + "\n");
            }
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Para leer los archivos uso este método, que mediante un boolean pasado por parámetro, elige uno u otro archivo:

```
    public ArrayList<String> leerArchivo(boolean orden, Context cont) {
        ArrayList<String> listaLlamadas = new ArrayList();
        File f;
        String linea;

        try {
            if (orden) {
                f = new File(cont.getFilesDir(), "Llamadas.csv");
            } else {
                f = new File(cont.getFilesDir(), "Historial.csv");
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {
                listaLlamadas.add(linea);
            }
            br.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaLlamadas;
    }
```

Si abres cualquiera de los dos archivos, los datos existen:

```
2020; 11; 02; 11; 10; 05; 20; RAMÓN;
2020; 11; 02; 11; 10; 14; 20; RAMÓN;
2020; 11; 02; 11; 10; 34; 20; RAMÓN;
2020; 11; 02; 11; 11; 11; 48; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 11; 11; 18; 12; Pepe Lopez;
2020; 11; 02; 11; 18; 07; 12; Pepe Lopez;
2020; 11; 02; 11; 54; 49; 12; Pepe Lopez;
2020; 11; 02; 11; 54; 59; 77667876; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 11; 56; 25; 11; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 20; 36; 11; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 21; 19; 11; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 21; 22; 11; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 21; 47; 11; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 22; 02; 11; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 22; 50; 166; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 32; 24; 3436; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 45; 23; 3436; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 46; 09; 3436; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 46; 33; 3436; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 48; 14; 3436; Desconocido;
2020; 11; 02; 12; 54; 46; 12; Pepe Lopez;
2020; 11; 02; 13; 01; 18; 12; Pepe Lopez;
2020; 11; 02; 13; 03; 23; 5048; Desconocido;
```

Para ordenar uno de los archivos, uso un arraylist, y mediante la serialización, la implementación del compareTo y Collection.sort, intento ordenarlo. Para hacerlo, creo un archivo serializable con el array de datos, para recuperarlo más tarde y ordenarlo. El problema es que a la hora de cargar el arraylist, no me carga nada, me lo devuelve vacío. Estos son los métodos de lectura y escritura del array serializable:

```
    public boolean escribeSerializable(Llamada llamadaLocal, Context cont) {
        ArrayList<Llamada> listaLlamadas = leeSerializable(cont);
        listaLlamadas.add(llamadaLocal);

        Log.v("HOLA", String.valueOf(cont.getExternalFilesDir("listaLlamadas.dat")));

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cont.getExternalFilesDir("listaLlamadas.dat"));
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            oos.writeObject(listaLlamadas);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<Llamada> leeSerializable(Context cont) {
        ArrayList<Llamada> listaLlamadas = new ArrayList();

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cont.getExternalFilesDir("listaLlamadas.dat"));
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            listaLlamadas = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            c.printStackTrace();
        }

        return listaLlamadas;
    }
```

Tengo supuestamente todos los permisos que necesito. No me da fallo de ningún tipo, simplemente que el arrayList me lo devuelve vacío.

¿Alguién podría ayudarme?

Gracias.

Comment: Tienes definidos que permisos en el AndroidManifest? y los requieres manualmente?

Comment: Si, en el manifiesto están definidos

Comment: que permiso ? los requieres manualmente?

Comment: Si si. Y están dado cuando ocurre esto